# Border-radius doesn't work on images?

Tags: css

```
.el img{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Am I missing something? Or this property really doesn't work with images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does work, only it needs to be used with vendor prefixes, as most browsers still don't support it as `border-radius` but only as `-webkit-border-radius` etc.

```
.el img{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

**[A working example](http://jsfiddle.net/azFK9/1)**

Comment: Neither in FireFox 3.6.23, nor Chrome 14.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome, I've added an example.

Comment: `<div><img></div>` doesn't work, though with `div {border-radius:10px;}` in webkit browsers (even with `-webkit-`) or Opera.

Comment: @doubleJ: No, but pay close attention, the style is applied on the image, not on the div.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this does work on images directly, you'll have to define that style on a div or similar element and add the image as a background. Cheers